# Design of tests in testing application

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm writing testing application in C# and i have a design/implementation question. 
My application will contain at least 20-30 tests, each test has 2 functions: init and main (these function are different for each test).

My question is how to implement it in the best way?

I thought about 2 solutions, but i am not quite with both of them:

1. Define an inteface with  2 function and then each test will be implemented as a class that implements this interface and one object. But my problem with this implementation that i don't think that it's right that test will be class and it increase the count of the classes in the whole project.
2. Define class Test that has 2 members from type METHOD and then for each class i'll pass in c'tor 2 functions. But in this implementation i fill like i'm using function pointers from C (i'm programming in C all the time) and not C# capabilities. And this implementation isn't safe at all.

So please suggest me better desing and implementation so i'll fill that i'm using in the right way C# capabilities.

Note: this isn't a unit tests application.

Comment: Why do you think the number of classes in 1) is a problem?

Comment: i think that 20-30 classes are too much for this application, i fill like it's wrong design to have so many classes for this purpose

Comment: What is the purpopse of `init` and `main` methods you mentioned? MSTest has two useful attributes, `ClassInitialize` and `TestInitialize`, paired with `ClassCleanUp` and `TestCleanUp`. These attributes allow you to run initialization and tear-down code for class and method level respectively. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: MSTest isn't only for unit tests? My tests are for HW, and not for testing code